# Fade in and out content for each slide in Twitter Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

With the following code I get the content of "#featured-carousel" to fade in and out of slide 2, 3, etc. 
However, not for the first slide.
 How do I get even first slide to fade in and out the very first time?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var color = "<?=$color?>";
            var header_color = "<?=$header_color?>";        

            $('#featured-carousel').bind('slide', function() {
                $(".carousel-caption").animate({'opacity': 0}, 500).delay(2000);  
                $(".item img").animate({'opacity': 1}, 500).delay(2000);          
                $(".carousel-caption").animate({'opacity': 1}, 500).delay(2000); 
                $(".item img").animate({'opacity': 0.2}, 500).delay(2000);                 
            }); 

            $('#featured-carousel').carousel({
                   interval: 6000,
                      cycle: true,          
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry I couldn't cope with your delays, so I used timeouts instead. That way, the animations are canceled when the carousel is navigated manually.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nXJ8J/)

First, some CSS to make the first item look like the beginning of the animation, but this can be done with some JS if you prefer :

```css
#myCarousel .carousel-caption {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

And then comes the animation part, divided in two bindings : when we start the animation and when we need to reset the appearance :

```js
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
var $carouselCaptions = $carousel.find('.item .carousel-caption');
var $carouselImages = $carousel.find('.item img');
var carouselTimeout;

$carousel.on('slid', function () {
    var $item = $carousel.find('.item.active');
    carouselTimeout = setTimeout(function() { // start the delay
        carouselTimeout = false;
        $item.find('.carousel-caption').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
        $item.find('img').animate({'opacity': 0.2}, 500);
    }, 2000);
}).on('slide', function () {
    if(carouselTimeout) { // Carousel is sliding, stop pending animation if any
        clearTimeout(carouselTimeout);
        carouselTimeout = false;
    }
    // Reset styles
    $carouselCaptions.animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
    $carouselImages.animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
});;

$carousel.carousel({
    interval: 6000,
    cycle: true,
}).trigger('slid'); // Make the carousel believe that it has just been slid so that the first item gets the animation
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sherbrow. Your code did the math exactly as I wanted it to!

Comment: Thanks.. really. You can check a modified version in http://demo.theme.firmasite.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap 3, you need to use **slide.bs.carousel** instead of **slide** and **slid.bs.carousel** instead of **slid**

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage Events Section.